# How to use percentage (floating) similarity fuzzy queries in Lucene?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

Lucene, version: 7.3.0.

All I want is to use percentage (floating) similarity fuzzy queries (`FuzzyQuery` class) in *Lucene*.

`defaultMinSimilarity` is now deprecated, so I can use only `defaultMaxEdits` for my purposes.

As far as I can see, maximal supported distance for `org.apache.lucene.search.FuzzyQuery` can't be more than 2:

```
MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_DISTANCE = 2
```

What if I want to search for *55%* similar strings, but for a term with a big length?
How can I do that with *Lucene*'s `FuzzyQuery`? 
Can I bypass that maximum-2-step edit distance restriction at all?

Answer (score 2):

Can you bypass that `FuzzyQuery` limitation? No. Can you do it at all? Almost certainly yes, but you need to rethink the problem a bit. `FuzzyQuery` is not the answer.

You should consider, instead, how you could use analysis to solve your problem. Indexing NGrams would be the most direct solution for very loose, fuzzy style matching, see [NGramTokenFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenFilter.html).

Comment: Thank you for you help!
Why so few people answering questions in that topic? Rhetorical question.